# How can I add a condition on a automatic flow in a Blueprint?

Tags: zoho

I am looking forward to automating some transitions in our current workflow based on follow ups. The thing is that our contacts have multiple languages, so I would like to send an email notification template based on the language (a field in the record) of the recipient. Is there a way to accomplish this from the blueprint? I really like this feature and it was not available when I first set up the blueprint, but its really useful and powerful!

So far, what I have theorized, is that I can make that this automatic transition updates a date-time field with the current time, and then set a workflow automation that would be triggered when this field is updated, and I could add a condition there to send an email based on the condition field of the language.

I think the above could work, but maybe there is already something in place and I don't have to make a dirty solution.

Comment: Why do you need the transition to be automatic, to send the emails ? Is this emails triggered from user action or by time ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom function that would get triggered with the workflow. The function would check the customer's language based on a custom field you would have defined. Depending on the value of that language field, the script would then send the specific template email that is written in that language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).